# How to make EF code first work under `IIS AppPool\MySiteName`?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am learning MVC 3 from asp.net site.

My MVC 3 application already has been tested under `IIS AppPool\MySiteName` and it works well.

Using Sql Server Management Studio, I created a new account for `IIS AppPool\MySiteName`.

I followed this tutorial ["creating db on the fly"](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part5-cs) and I got an error as follows:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Cannot open database "Movies" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\Getting Started'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Comment: Set `Load User Profile = True` on the application pool `Getting Started`. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Load User Profile` to `True` on the application pool `GettingStarted`.

Comment: Here is an excellent tutorial: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well that error is saying that the user IIS APPPOOL\Getting Started doesn't have the proper login credentials, either your username or password is incorrect. Why not show us what the connection string looks like in your web.config file

Answer (score 1):

The following things is all you should have to do imo:

1. Create and configure a new AppPool,
   say *AppPoolFoo*, running under the
   identity of a local user account,
   say **User1**
2. Configure your site in IIS to run
   under *AppPoolFoo*
3. Grant **User1** appropriate rights with
   SQL Server Management Studio

It's unclear to me whether you followed these steps, or have a different scenario.

Comment: @xport: How exactly did you create the account/login in SQL Server? I finally realize you are runder an Application Poool identity "virtual" account, this article might help: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/